# PHP $_GET not giving me required result

Tags: php

I am writing a PHP code in Adobe Dreamweaver. My code is as shown below. I am expecting my code to output two boxes, into which I write something. And when I click on the submit button, I expect to see the two separate things that I entered into the box to be concatenated. But I'm not getting a concatenation. In fact, NOTHING happens when I click on submit. I am confused. Is this code not something I should be using Dreamweaver for? I am relatively new to PHP and I do not understand all the bits. My suspicion is that Dreamweaver does not recognize "twoFieldForm.php". Can someone please tell me how I can overcome this issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
<h1>Form Filler</h1>

    <?php

    function joined($s1, $s2) {
        return array($s1.$s2, strlen($s1.$s2));
    }

    $first = $_GET[fieldOne];
    $second = $_GET[fieldTwo];
    $answer = joined($first, $second);
      echo "The concatenated string is \"{$answer[0]}\" 
      and its length is \"{$answer[1]}\";
    ?>

    <form action = "twoFieldForm.php" method = "get">
    Field 1 : <input type = "text" name = "fieldOne"/>
    Field 2 : <input type = "text" name = "fieldTwo"/>
      <input type = "submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is so beautiful

Comment: Have you tried defining which parts of `$_GET` you want? Perhaps `$_GET['fieldOne']`? Note the apostrophes so it's a literal name rather than a variable name. I would have expected some sort of warning about using an assigned variable, though: are you reporting errors/warnings?

Comment: Is the posted file _twoFieldForm.php_?

Comment: Andrew, thanks for your comments. There were no warnings about unassigned vbles.

Comment: @scorpion. It's a good thing for you to admire other people's code...

Comment: @KonstantinosChertouras I'm wondering if you know what makes it good?

Answer (score 7):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
<h1>Form Filler</h1>

<?php

    function joined($s1, $s2) {
        return array($s1.$s2, strlen($s1.$s2));
    }

    $first = $_GET['fieldOne'];
    $second = $_GET['fieldTwo'];
    $answer = joined($first, $second);
    echo "The concatenated string is \"{$answer[0]}\" 
    and its length is \"{$answer[1]}\"";
?>

<form action="" method="GET">
    Field 1 : <input type="text" name="fieldOne"/>
    Field 2 : <input type="text" name="fieldTwo"/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Explanation: You have to add quotes in $_GET['']. Remember indention please, always when I see people using adobe dreamweaver, their code is horrible... If you are refering to the same file, you don't have to use an action="somewhat.php". Just leave it **empty**. Aswell you have missed a " after your echo statement.
This will work now. Please start using a good IDE then you won't have those basic mistakes because the IDE will show you your mistakes already...

Comment: "Solution" already posted and is not correct (as I commented there)

Comment: This solution wasnt posted yet. He probably did NOT name the file correct. Read my answer before instant downvoting me. Thanks! - you downvoted 1 second after I submitted...

Comment: How do you know if it was him? I'll upvote your answer just for fun

Comment: Because he instant commented. Anyways, this IS working so remove the -1. Thanks..

Comment: @Xatenev Touché! Missing `"` is a good catch but `action` is still a guess

Comment: I have just tried it out local, this wporks now, He was missing the " and probably his filename is incorrect.

Comment: Xatanev, ok, now I understand that the action="" is redundant if referring to same file. Thank you.

Comment: @JakeGould <form action="#".."> will try to search for an anchor or just stay on the same file and will NOT reload again. This is the way to submit to the same page.

Comment: Xanatev, I've accepted your answer. Thank you kindly.

Comment: @user2975787 You did not^^ accepting means xyou click the "check-button" just near the upvote ^^

Answer (score 2):

Try add quotes:

```
  $first = $_GET['fieldOne'];
  $second = $_GET['fieldTwo'];
```

Comment: Shouldn't be the problem ([proof](http://3v4l.org/Siak9)), does trigger Notice but works

Comment: Use of undefined constant `fieldOne` is no problem? ok:)

Comment: Of course it isn't best practice, but the code still works, doesn't it?

Comment: @kingkero No it does not... that would try to search for a constant without the quotes... and it would not refer to the submitted input fields. It will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$answer=$_GET['fieldOne'].$_GET['fieldTwo'];
echo "concatenated string is:".$answer;
```

try this...